# Create new users in Windows 7 with no groups

Tags: windows-7, users, user-groups

In Windows 7 if I create a new user from "Computer Management" -> "Local Users and Groups", this new user will belong to the "Users" group. Is there a way to have new users created by default without "Users" group?

Comment: Welcome to Super User. Please update your question (not in comments) with details of what you are attempting to accomplish by not having the user in the "users" group? This will help us understand what you are trying to do overall and offer possible alternatives if what you ask is not possible. Also, please tell us what you have researched and attempted to resolve this.

Comment: So you want to change the user group that is used by default?  If that is the case update your question.